# Curl script with offset increment

Tags: linux, scripting, curl

how to increment offset number in curl script?

my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -a --silent --header "api-key: 4444444455" --header "accept: application/xml" --header "cache-control: no-store" "https://gghghghg.com/api/invoices?supplier%5Bid%5D%5Bnot_eq%5D=109789%3F&limit=50&offset=150" >  /bi01/In_API_Call_Data.txt 2>&1 
exit 0
```

Comment: (1) There's no such thing as a curl script.  You have a bash script (which calls curl).  (2) Please describe more clearly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you Scott for quick response. pardon my ignorance in scripting, I am pretty much new to all of it.  >>   I need to write a script which will increment the offset parameter in the above Curl call Until there are no records there.

Comment: (If I'm reading this correct) `offset` in your example is part of the query string for the URI request. What you need is a `while` loop with a variable that is substituted for that value.

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve your problem please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/391918/edit) and explain your problem including an example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want *offset* go from 150 to 155, and also shorten the command so I could explain it better.

You can increment *offset* with a `for` loop and using variable `i` as *offset*:

```
for i in {150..155}; do
    curl --header "kk: vv" "http://example.com/path&offset=$i" >outfile$i 2>&1
done
```

#### Notes:

- I put `$i` in `>outfile$i`, assuming that you want to keep all responses for all *offests*. Without `$i` in file name all `curl` calls write to the same file and overwrite it, only keeping the last `curl` result.
- Instead of `>outfile$i 2>&1` you can use `&>outfile$i`, but it may not work in some (older) shells.
- You can achieve the same thing with a `for` like `for ((i=150; i<=155; ++i)); do` or `for i in $(seq 150 155); do`. Some form may be more readable/familiar for you, but makes no difference in this example.
- It's simpler to use curly braces expansion for cases like this, and creating multiple URLs for the `curl`:

  ```
  curl --header "kk: vv" "http://example.com/path&offset="{150..155} >>outfile 2>&1
  ```

  But it can't write each response to separate file. Instead you can append all responses to one file by using `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..150,160}; do
  curl -asH "api-key: 4444444455" -H "accept: application/xml" -H "cache-control: no-store" "https://gghghghg.com/api/invoices?supplier%5Bid%5D%5Bnot_eq%5D=109789%3F&limit=50&offset="$i >/bi01/In_API_Call_Data.txt 2>&1
done
exit 0
```

You can use a simple `for` loop to change your URL, the above example will take all numbers from `0` to `150` and `160`.